# Declaration of method via curly brackets in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

How to read declaration of method in this manner (or how compiler reads it):

```
add: {(id: number): void}
```

**Is this like creating a `type` for this `add` method?** It's strange as this reads like `add` is object with one function.

**context:**

```
interface ComponentProps {
  add: {(id: number): void};
}
```

and then when some React component implements this I will write:

```
<Component add={(item) => {console.log(`Added item ${item}`);} } />
```

Comment: Could you provide more context? If `add` is an object property - then it does not look like a valid TS code.

Comment: As far as I know, this syntax is not valid (like @zerkms said).

Comment: It's a valid syntax.

Comment: Can you provide a sample @MuratK.

Comment: @UmutOzel it's a class method. In that case it's valid. The question could have been cleaner, so that we did not have to guess.

Comment: Declare it as a variable and call it

Comment: Ok ok, then it is a class that has a method member whose name is an anonymous function.

Comment: @MuratK. with first given code piece, how can you declare a variable and call it? Without guessing it's a class or object definition. You mean something like this var a = add: {(id: number): void};
How can this be valid?

Comment: @UmutOzel `var add: {(id: number): void} = (id:number) => console.log("like this");`

Comment: Of course this is valid, but how can we guess what OP meant (before editing the question), you can use in an interface, or in variable declaration (like you did). I meant this syntax is not valid as it is (as an expression), like @zerkms said, we didn't know the context).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`add` is a field that is a function. The way we usually write a function signature type in typescript is `(id: number) => void` but this is a short form of `{ (id: number): void }`. The two syntaxes are equivalent, both define a type that has a callable signature. This more verbose syntax has the advantage of allowing more signatures:

```
interface ComponentProps {
  add: {
     (id: number): void
     (id: string, otherParam: number): void
  };
}
```